# Cannot jail ssh account using ChrootDirectory

Tags: linux, ssh, centos-6, sshd, chroot-jail

I am trying to jail my accounts into their home directory. I tried to do:

```
Match group accounts
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
```

Then naturally:
`service sshd restart`

As this is listed numerous times on SU and around the web but this doesn't seem to really do anything, at least not that I can tell as my user is still able to get to directories outside their home and edit files outside their home.

I am using: `CentOS release 6.5 (Final)`

ssh is: `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`

I have the *accounts* group to restrict access to only their home directory. The home directory is located in `/var/www/vhosts/<-account>` they then have a `public_html` folder. I want the user to be able to store files outside of their webroot but I want them to be jailed in their home folder. It should be noted that the permissions for the home directory are to the `accountName:apache`, not `root:root`.

In group I have:

```
accountName:x:509:
accounts:x:510:accountName
```

passwd:`accountName:x:507:509::/var/www/vhosts/accountName/public_html/:/bin/bash`

Am I missing something here? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

I checked EOL and made sure they are all UNIX as I read that on another post.

*accountName* is replaced by actual account name. I'm not using that as my account.

Thanks for any help/info on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I read in `man sshd_config` is "All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group." I would think that would exclude home directories.

Comment: Thanks. I did read that too but I am still not able to get this working. I have root user and group on the www folder but I didn't want to for the home directory. I am assuming this is the cause for it not working. I need to have the accounts access outside of webroot. I'll have to do more research on this and update my question to reflect my findings.